# (GPS) GPS-610F / jupiter-610f

Tags: gps

I bought few pieces of GPS modules (jupiter-610f, http://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/acatalog/info_GPS_610F.html) from online shop.

I tried to connect the GPS module to PC thought a USB to TTL 3.3V converter (
http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?spm=2013.1.0.0.wymWWk&scm=1007.10009.518.0&id=18313941913&pvid=51e783b9-f467-4297-bbe2-2f4df1fc78df
)

Connect is as follow,

```
   pin1 (GPS) Serial Data      <-> (USB) RX 
   pin2 (GPS) Serial Data In 1 <-> (USB) TX 
   pin3 (GPS) VCC              <-> (USB) 3.3VDC 
   pin4 (GPS) GND              <-> (USB) GND
   pin5 (GPS) PIO Output       <-> (USB) NC
   pin6 (GPS) 1PPS             <-> (USB) NC
   pin7 (GPS) RESET IN         <-> (USB) NC
   pin8 (GPS) Serial Data In 2 <-> (USB) NC
   pin9 (GPS) VBAT             <-> (USB) NC
   pin10 (GPS) Antenna Power   <-> (USB) 5VDC
```

I use LSViewer.exe to study the result.

However, it does not work. No response from the device.

Regards,
Angus

Answer (score 1):

Check the devices datasheet. Check the placement of the Antenna. Make sure your power source can provide enough power. Then check for connections again. First use something like putty! or some serial monitor. Such things are easy not to go wrong.

if you are using windows, go to system properties and find out which COM port the GPS is connected to.Afterwards, open the COM port via putty setting the BAUD RATE set on the GPS module. if BAUDs match, you will see data on the putty serial termial.